# Determine if U a subspace of $P_3$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, axioms

U= The set of all polynomials in $P_3$ with constant term 0.

I'm not exactly sure how to go about this question... I know I have to prove Axioms A1, A4, and S1.

A1.If x∈W and y∈W, then x+y∈W.
A4.W is nonempty, W≠∅.
S1.If α∈C and x∈W, then αx∈W.

However, I'm not exactly sure how to do so... Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just write generic polynomials in $P_3$ as $aX+bX^2+cX^3$ and check.

Comment: In your three axioms, $W$ should be written as $U.$ For example, the first axiom is just asking you to show that the sum of two polynomials with constant term 0 is also a polynomial of constant term 0. I will leave it to you to interpret the other two.

Comment: @Dfrtbx so then for A1. Would it be If $a_1X+a_2X^2+a_3X^3=0$ ∈ $U$ and  $b_1X+b_2X^2+b_3X^3=0$ ∈ $U$ then  $(a_1X+a_2X^2+a_3X^3)+(b_1X+b_2X^2+b_3X^3)=0$ ∈ $U$ ?

Comment: or is it $a_1=a_2=a_3=0$

Comment: @Bernard Can you see if my comment above makes sense?

Comment: Why should these polynomials be $0$? Their degree has just  to be no more than$3$ and  no constant terms, and you  should check it's the same if you add them. Similarly for scalar multiplication. As to A4$, you just have to find one such polynomial.

Comment: TaljanaD, you are mostly correct, as @Bernard points out there is no reason that these polynomials should equal 0. All that is necessary is that the constant term be 0, by definition.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned you have to prove that the subspace is $a.$ not empty b. closed to linear combinations.

$U=\{a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3:a_0=0\}$

So $(0,0,0,0)\in U$ so $U$ is not empty.

Let there be $u_1,u_2\in U$ and $\alpha\in \mathbb{F}$ so $u_1+\alpha\cdot u_2=a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+\alpha(b_1x+b_2x^2+b_3x^3)=a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+\alpha
 \cdot b_1x+\alpha \cdot b_2x^2+\alpha \cdot b_3x^3)=(a_1+\alpha \cdot b_1)x+(a_2+\alpha \cdot b_2)x^2+(a_3+\alpha \cdot b_3)x^3 \in U$

So $U$ is a subspace of $P_3$